# What is the best way to let co-workers install an iPhone app that is in development

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-application

I am new to iPhone app development. I am confused by what it takes to install an iPhone app on my co-workers phones before I publish it to App Store. Many thanks.

Comment: Use TestFlight.

Comment: Wow, many thanks. I am puzzled why I was not able to find this via Google, etc.

Comment: It's all documented by Apple.